# Flutter Transition to new page with Animation

Tags: dart, flutter

Somewhat like these Animation i want to achieve...Specially while transition to new page Upon click it should Animate vertically and Navigate to new Page, same should happen when i want to re navigate to previous Page?
Has Anyone worked on it or any useful links ?[Animation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4QQ2.gif)

Answer (score 0):

[Animating a Widget across screens](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/hero-animations/) might be helpful.